# Nagios 4 on Centos 7 - Old server

Tags: centos, nagios, systemctl, omdistro

I am trying to install Nagios 4 on an old Pentium 4 machine running Centos 7. I have installed the OS from the x86_64 ISO provided at the website. Nagios is downloaded with wget from Sourceforge. I have followed [these](http://linoxide.com/how-tos/install-configure-nagios-centos-7/) instructions to the letter, but every time I seem to hit a wall at the same spot. First these commands refuse to execute:

```
chkconfig --add httpd
chkconfig --level 35 httpd on
```

And then this command does not complete:

```
systemctl start nagios.service
```

The message I receive says that it failed and the reason is "resources".

**UPDATE:**

I decided to go the "OMD" way as was suggested in one comment.

The package installed correctly from the EPEL repository. When I run `omd start sitename` the output implies that everything works correctly.

When I try to view the GUI from Lynx (I have to use a command line browser for the time being) first it shows a `503 Error` and then something along the lines of `"Site not started - You need to start the site to be able to launch the GUI"`. The only indication of something going wrong is some lines in the apache error_log that start with `proxy:error` and `http_proxy:error`.

Comment: You have to post the whole error.  There isn't enough information to work with.  

Also, is there anything in the nagios log file?

Comment: Nagios needs resources. I bet you don't have enough RAM.

Comment: I will post an update tomorrow from work.

Comment: Don't install NAGIOS that way.  Activate the EPEL repo, which can usually be done with `yum install epel-release`, then install NAGIOS with `yum install nagios`.  The integration is much better, as it's built specifically for RH/C7.

Comment: @MadHatter Will check it tomorrow. Seems perfect though. I will post an update as soon as I go to the office and check it out.

Comment: Fair enough, though I took a quick look at the C7 manifest and it's only NAGIOS 3.5.x.  Do you have a business need for 4?

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into [OMD](http://omdistro.org/), Open Monitoring Distribution.